# See child gameObjects from code

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is it possible to put parent gameObject in UnityEditor and see child gameObjects from code? I tried to create custom class with necessary structure, nut unity doesn't understand it.

```
public Path Path1;
public Path Path2;
public Path Path3;
public Path Path4;
```

[image]

```
[Serializable]
public class Path : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Way> Ways;

    public Path ()
    {
    }
}
```

Way class

```
[Serializable]
public class Way : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform StartPoint { get; set;}
    public Transform[] EndPoints { get; set;}
    public Transform[] AngleWaypoints { get; set;}

    public Way ()
    {
    }
    public Way (Transform startPoint, Transform[] endPoints, Transform[] angleWaypoints)
    {
        this.StartPoint = startPoint;
        this.EndPoints = endPoints;
        this.AngleWaypoints = angleWaypoints;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class needs to inherit from MonoBehaviour, maybe it is it that your missing.

It should look like

```
 class myClass : MonoBehaviour{
 }
```

You have selected your GameManager script. Try selecting Path_1, all public variables of Path class should appear in the UnityEditor.

Also you can change the UnityEditor Mode to Debug, which will show much more information [UnityEditor Debug Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h62n1.png)

Comment: No effect. I'm trying put GameObject on Path class

Comment: Could you add your code or a screenshot of UnityEditor to help clarify this issue?

Comment: And, not sure if I understand your problem correctlly but, I can see that in GameManager Path1 is None. Path_1 needs to be dragged into GameManager's script in order to store its reference.

Comment: I can't drag Path_1 into GameManager's Path1. Because they have different types. That is my question

Comment: Ok found out. It is my fault. It is necessary to bind Path_1 with Path class code, dropping it on game object. Then types will be the same and it would be possible to drag it into Gameobject's script

Comment: You weren't attaching the script Path to the GameObject Path_1 then? Glad you found out!